# link to SFML 2 throws undefined reference to sf::Window constructor

Tags: c++, linker-errors, sfml

I just wanted to move my program source on my new computer and installed Codeblocks 12.11 and compiled SFML 2 by myself following the latest instructions by SFMLCoder. Everything worked fine. When I try to compile this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    sf::Window w( sf::VideoMode( 800, 600 ), "test" );

    return 0;
}
```

I tried the static(with defining SFML_STATIC in C::B in the Buildoptions), the dynamic and both of the debug libs. But always after it links the files it says:
`main.cpp|11|undefined reference to sf::Window::Window(sf::VideoMode, std::string const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)`
or when using dynamic libraries
`main.cpp|11|undefined reference to _imp___ZN2sf6WindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKSsjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE`
which is obviously the equivalent to the static link error.

Edit:
I found a thread in the official [SFML-forum](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=10619.0) with the exactly same problem: I'll post the solution if I get it right.

Comment: What command are you running to compile?

Comment: @Xymostech I compiled SFML 2 via CMake and C::B compiles the main.cpp by executing this `mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions  -g    -IC:\Users\User\CBP\Test\  -c C:\Users\User\CBP\Test\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
` and links with `mingw32-g++.exe  -o .\Publish\Test.exe obj\Debug\main.o    ..\..\..\..\sfml2\lib\libsfml-graphics-d.a ..\..\..\..\sfml2\lib\libsfml-system-d.a ..\..\..\..\sfml2\lib\libsfml-window-d.a
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Hmm... [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996792/making-a-sfml2-applcation-with-clang-libc-and-c11-undefined-reference-to-s) sounds pretty similar to your question, and they had a problem because sfml and their program were being compiled with different settings... Did cmake use mingw32-g++ to compile it? (You might be able to check by re-running the make with `make VERBOSE=1`)

Comment: @Xymostech I specified the MinGW Makefile and defined the native compilers which were mingw32-g++(out of the C::B MinGW dir) and none (for C and Fortran).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added myself into [this discussion](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=10619.15) and it reveals that I had to download the version from github and I had to include SFML/Window.hpp. It works from now on. Hope this answer helps others too.